# Python: Json unpacking into a dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to parse json  I've recieved from an api into a pandas DataFrame. That json is ierarchical, in this example I have city code, line name and list of stations for this line. Unfortunately I can't "unpack" it. Would be gratefull for help and explanation.

Json:

```
{'id': '1',
 'lines': [{'hex_color': 'FFCD1C',
   'id': '8',
   'name': 'Калининская',          <------Line name
   'stations': [{'id': '8.189',
     'lat': 55.745113,
     'lng': 37.864052,
     'name': 'Новокосино',         <------Station 1   
     'order': 0},
    {'id': '8.88',
     'lat': 55.752237,
     'lng': 37.814587,
     'name': 'Новогиреево',        <------Station 2
     'order': 1},
etc.
```

I'm trying to recieve evrything from lowest level and the add all higher level information (starting from linename):

```
c = r.content
j = simplejson.loads(c)

tmp=[]
i=0
data1=pd.DataFrame(tmp)
data2=pd.DataFrame(tmp)

pd.concat
station['name']

for station in j['lines']:

    data2 = data2.append(pd.DataFrame(station['stations'], station['name']),ignore_index=True)
data2
```

Once more - the questions are:
How to make it work?
Is this solution an optimal one, or there are some functions I should know about?

**Update:**
The Json parses normally:

```
json_normalize(j)

id  lines                                              name
1   [{'hex_color': 'FFCD1C', 'stations': [{'lat': ...   Москва
```

Current DataFrame I can get:

```
data2 = data2.append(pd.DataFrame(station['stations']),ignore_index=True)
    id      lat         lng         name        order
0   8.189   55.745113   37.864052   Новокосино  0
1   8.88    55.752237   37.814587   Новогиреево 1
```

Desired dataframe can be represented as:

```
id  lat     lng                     name            order  Line_Name    Id_Top Name_Top
0   8.189   55.745113   37.864052   Новокосино      0      Калининская  1       Москва 
1   8.88    55.752237   37.814587   Новогиреево     1      Калининская  1       Москва
```

Comment: please post a JSON with at least two top-level elements (`'id': '1'` and `'id': '2'`) and make sure that it can be parsed (it should be a valid JSON/dictionary) and provide your desired data set

Comment: @MaxU it is funny, but the Json I'm working with now have only 1 top-level element. I'll edit the question in a minute.

Comment: OK, can you post your desired data set / DF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the following dictionary:

```
In [70]: data
Out[70]:
{'id': '1',
 'lines': [{'hex_color': 'FFCD1C',
   'id': '8',
   'name': 'Калининская',
   'stations': [{'id': '8.189',
     'lat': 55.745113,
     'lng': 37.864052,
     'name': 'Новокосино',
     'order': 0},
    {'id': '8.88',
     'lat': 55.752237,
     'lng': 37.814587,
     'name': 'Новогиреево',
     'order': 1}]}]}
```

**Solution:** use [pandas.io.json.json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
In [71]: pd.io.json.json_normalize(data['lines'],
                                   ['stations'],
                                   ['name', 'id'],
                                   meta_prefix='parent_')
Out[71]:
      id        lat        lng         name  order  parent_name parent_id
0  8.189  55.745113  37.864052   Новокосино      0  Калининская         8
1   8.88  55.752237  37.814587  Новогиреево      1  Калининская         8
```

**UPDATE:** reflects updated question

```
res = (pd.io.json.json_normalize(data,
                                 ['lines', 'stations'],
                                 ['id', ['lines', 'name']],
                                 meta_prefix='Line_')
         .assign(Name_Top='Москва'))
```

Result:

```
In [94]: res
Out[94]:
      id        lat        lng         name  order Line_id Line_lines.name Name_Top
0  8.189  55.745113  37.864052   Новокосино      0       1     Калининская   Москва
1   8.88  55.752237  37.814587  Новогиреево      1       1     Калининская   Москва
```

Comment: Thank you! That solves like 80% of the problem and much more elegant than my solution. Yet there are 2 levels higher than name one, how one more parent level could be added?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to MaxU's answer, I think you still need the highest level `id`, this should work:

```
json_normalize(data, ['lines','stations'], ['id',['lines','name']],record_prefix='station_')
```

Comment: Thanks! That is it!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: Nice one ! +1 :-)